# How to properly create a Joy Node or any node

Tags: ros, joy-node, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made this post because I couldn`t find any detailed explanation on the web about how to build a node from scratch and it may help anyone trying to self-learn ROS.
I tried to build a node for controlling the Turtle sim using my PS4 joystick using different buttons and axis with learning purpose for later applying at my robot.

However while trying to run I receive back the message:

**couldn`t find executable named teleop_joy below /home/rmb/workspace1/src/test_node**

My code: https://github.com/renanmb/SURP

It happens using rosrun and roslaunch. I don`t understand why since I tryied to keep the code very similar to the code found at the Ros Joy Tutorial ( http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode ).

I also used as example the code found at JetsonHacks https://github.com/jetsonhacks/jetsoncar_teleop

Thanks for the support.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264506/how-to-properly-create-a-joy-node-or-any-node./) by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-06-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
Probably not the answer you are looking for, but: have you completed the regular -- beginner -- ROS tutorials on the wiki? This would seem to be something that is covered there.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
One thing to check: have you built your workspace (ie: ran `catkin_make`) and then `source`d the `devel/setup.bash` file?

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-06-22**:
Yes, I did all tutorials.
I know that I need to compile running catkin_make or cmake, and for each workspace that I will be working with I need to source the devel/setup.bash . I followed all that and still get the message that there is no executable. The mistake is probably at CMakeLists, file .cpp

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
If I try to compile your code, I get three compiler errors. Is the code on your github repo identical to what you have on your machine? If so, then it would make sense that `rosrun` can't find `teleop_joy`, as it won't be created due to the compiler failing.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
If I fix those errors, the binary is generated and after `source devel/setup.bash` I can successfully run: `rosrun test_node teleop_joy`. The `CMakeLists.txt` seems ok. At least on my end only the compiler errors were preventing things from working.

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-06-22**:
but why the compiler is failing? Is It probably something in the CMakeLists? I don`t know what I made wrong because I just followed like it says in the Tutorial.
I not included the directory include, but I think is only necessary CMakeLists.txt , package.xml and the executable in the src directory.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
There is nothing wrong with `CMakeLists.txt`. See my answer.

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-06-22**:
So what was the errors in the compiler? I got lost trying to learn CMake in 1 night.
So do you think it is an installation problem with the compiler? Both my devices run on ARM 64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Bit of a strange answer, but see below for the diff that shows how I fixed the errors in your program:

```
diff --git a/src/teleop_joy.cpp b/src/teleop_joy.cpp
index 740d928..645d14a 100644
--- a/src/teleop_joy.cpp
+++ b/src/teleop_joy.cpp
@@ -37,12 +37,12 @@ TeleopTurtle::TeleopTurtle():
   angular_(0),
   deadman_axis_(4),
   l_scale_(2.0),
-  a_scale(2.0)
+  a_scale_(2.0)
 {

   ph_.param("axis_linear", linear_, linear_);
   ph_.param("axis_angular", angular_, angular_);
-  ph.param("axis_deadman", deadman_axis_, deadman_axis_);
+  ph_.param("axis_deadman", deadman_axis_, deadman_axis_);
   ph_.param("scale_angular", a_scale_, a_scale_);
   ph_.param("scale_linear", l_scale_, l_scale_);

@@ -53,7 +53,7 @@ TeleopTurtle::TeleopTurtle():

   joy_sub_ = nh_.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Joy>("joy", 10, &TeleopTurtle::joyCallback, this);

-  timer_ = nh_.createTimer(ros::Duration(0.1), boost::bind(&TurtlebotTeleop::publish, this));
+  timer_ = nh_.createTimer(ros::Duration(0.1), boost::bind(&TeleopTurtle::publish, this));
 }
```

After that I could successfully build the workspace and after `source devel/setup.bash` everything 'just worked'.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-22**:
PS: if I may suggest: unless you are writing a teleop node for the learning experience, I would really suggest you see if [teleop_twist_joy](http://wiki.ros.org/teleop_twist_joy) works for what you need. Always better to reuse than to reimplement.

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2017-06-22**:
My mistake was terrible. I may need a pair of glasses. But the code still doesnt work as supposed. I believe it can be button mapping for the DS4 or I made a mess trying to put this "Deadman" button.
I am writing it for learning experience, reusing is fast but dont teach as much as trying to write

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-23**:
`teleop_twist_joy` could still be a reference for what you are trying to achieve. It depends a bit on what you want to spend your time: getting your robot to work or fight with joysticks.

**Comment by [renanmb](https://answers.ros.org/users/30864/renanmb/) on 2018-09-23**:
Later on I solved the problem by trial and error and making a controller mapping. I was writing a teleop  node for the learning experience and later on I applied on some projects that required personalized teleop node